# MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a few questions regarding stored procedures. After hours of googling, I really can't find any really simple query examples.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1(IN uid INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT USER_NAME FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = uid;
END //
```

this query takes 'uid' as input and selects the username for that uid,
Can someone please explain how I call that procedure in php and also, how do I output the actual rows to the php var?

Comment: Using what database interface? mysqli? PDO? Something else?

Comment: I have inserted the stored procedure using phpmyadmin, but i'm trying to execute through php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider doing this with a stored function that returns a single VARCHAR:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test1(uid INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_RETURN_VAL VARCHAR(100);

    SELECT USER_NAME 
    INTO V_RETURN_VAL
    FROM USERS 
    WHERE USER_ID = uid;

    RETURN V_RETURN_VAL;
END //
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you just need to put call before it in the query:

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL test1(".$args.")");
$username = mysql_result($result);
```

Comment: But don't I have to define an 'OUT' var in the procedure in order to get the selected rows to the php var?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "CALL" and retrieve the rows as if it were a normal query.

The only case where it is different is if the procedure returns multiple result sets, in which case you MUST go through them all (even empty ones) with a method which gives the next result set.

OUT parameters are a waste of time as they require more round-trips and server-side state to fetch their results; you invariably write more code and have more bugs if you use them.